# How to fix the buzzing noise from external speakers

Tags: sound, noise

I have been experiencing this issue since ever but never knew how to fix it.
When my TV is connected to external speakers, there is a slight buzzing noise from the speakers. It increases when the volume in the TV or the ext. speakers is increased.

The same case when a guitar is connected to the speaker. I thought it could an issue with the jacks or the wires and changed them, but it persists.

What causes this noise actually. Is the reason same for both the above cases. Can this be fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's either a ground-loop problem or an induction problem in the cable connecting the television with the amplifier that drives the speakers. You should ensure that the TV and amplifier are connected to the same ground and that the audio cable connecting the TV and the amplifier does not cross any mains cables. If this does not fix it, you probably have a faulty TV or amplifier. This question is probably going to get closed out because it relates to home theatre / consumer audio.